# Mathematical history: non-rigorous approach leading to correct result

Tags: math-history, big-list

My question is,

> In the history of mathematics, what are some non-rigorous approaches that lead to a correct result?

One example I can think of is Euler’s initial approach to solve the Basel problem.

His argument is

> Because $n\pi$ is a root of $\sin x$, so $$\sin x=x(1+\frac{x}\pi)(1-\frac{x}{\pi})(1+\frac{x}{2\pi})(1-\frac{x}{2\pi})\cdots$$
>
> Equating the Taylor series and the product series of $\frac{\sin x}x$ and compare the coefficients of $x^2$, one obtains $$-\frac1{\pi^2}\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac1{n^2}=-\frac16$$ which solves the problem.

Obviously, the expansion of function in terms of its roots is not always correct, and requires the justification of Weierstrass factorization theorem, which was not available at the time.

What are some other (famous) examples?

Comment: Related: [In the history of mathematics, has there ever been a mistake?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139503/in-the-history-of-mathematics-has-there-ever-been-a-mistake) on MSE, and [What are some correct results discovered with incorrect (or no) proofs?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27749/what-are-some-correct-results-discovered-with-incorrect-or-no-proofs) on MO.

Comment: @dxiv I think the MSE post is quite different. The mistakes lead to wrong results, but non-rigorous proofs can lead to correct results.

Comment: Some of the answers on MSE do in fact provide examples of flawed proofs with correct results e.g. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139503/in-the-history-of-mathematics-has-there-ever-been-a-mistake#comment321102_139503), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139503/in-the-history-of-mathematics-has-there-ever-been-a-mistake/2746880#2746880), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139503/in-the-history-of-mathematics-has-there-ever-been-a-mistake/852346#852346).

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, there was no logical definition of $\Bbb R$ and no rigorous foundation for basic calculus, until the 19th century. In the 18th century some theologians mocked mathematicians for their belief in infinitesimals. A vast corpus of original discovery was  achieved with what, by today's standards, was a non-rigorous base.  Here is an example of a style of proof that was perfectly acceptable in the 17th century:

If $a_n\geq a_{n+1}\geq 0$ for each $n\in \Bbb N$ and if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges then $\lim_{N\to \infty}Na_N=0.$ PROOF: For $M,N \in \Bbb N$ with $M<N$ we have $$0\leq Na_N=\frac {1}{1-\frac {M}{N}}(N-M)a_N\leq \frac {1}{1-\frac {M}{N}}\sum_{n=M+1}^Na_n.$$  Now if $M$ is infinitely large  then  $\sum_{n=M+1}^{\infty}a_n$ is infinitely small, and we have $0\leq\sum_{n=M+1}^Na_n\leq \sum_{n=M}^{\infty}a_n,$ so $\sum_{n=M+1}^N a_n$ is infinitely small. And when $N$ is infinitely larger than $M$  the value of $\frac {1}{1-\frac {M}{N}}$ is infinitely close to $1$.

Comment: Haha. The proof makes no sense, especially for the last line: what if I set $N=M+1$?

Comment: You can't set $N=M+1$ because $N$ is infinitely larger than $M$. That is, $M/N$ is infinitely close to $0$. You can transform this into a modern 
 "$\epsilon$-$\delta$" proof with no difficulty